# The word-browser in Rebol View2 is broken

Tags: rebol, rebol2

The word browser is no longer working for me in Rebol2. Perhaps it can't download data from the rebol.com website. How can I get it working? I find nothing about this on stackoverflow.com or doing a google search.

Comment: Just tested Rebol/View on OS X (Mavericks) here and the Word Browser (listed under the `/REBOL Central Folder/REBOL Documentation/`) worked fine for me.  Do you still have a problem @Louis ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not looking for browse instead?

```
>> source browser
browser: undefined
>> source browse
browse: native [
    "Opens the default web browser."
    value [any-string!] "The URL or file to open"
    /only "Don't open a new window if possible"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the whole package in this zip file:   http://re-bol.com/wordbrowser.zip

Answer (score 0):

I'm regularly using the word browser, it works well on my GNU/Linux Debian Jessie machine.

```
>> write %wordbrowser.r read http://re-bol.com/wordbrowser.r
>> do %wordbrowser.r
```

Is your rebol/view interpreter correctly running?